# Loop on clickhouse tables

Tags: database, loops, artificial-intelligence, bigdata, clickhouse

How can I loop on a table in clickhouse database? Clickhouse dosen't have loop and stored procedures for some iterable scenario.

I want to chang pandas queris to SQL but I have for loop on the table but in Clickhouse we don't have these commands.what shall I do in these situation?

Comment: Pandas? Dataframe? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udlfgc5eVTY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for loop in SQL can be implemented by self-join command. I could do a for-loop scenario by joining the table with itself and then applying the condition to the joined table.
In general, for each loop, you need a self-join command and even less if you have enough mastery in SQL.

Comment: Weird. But maybe this can help with nested for loops over a single collection

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

SQL statements are performing operations on sets of data, so iterating through a collection of rows is pointless.
There is a chance that control-of-flow statements can help you (such as `CASE`):

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [8, 12, 5, 14, 10]})

# Increment 'value' by 1 if it's greater than 10
result_values = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['value'] > 10:
        result_values.append(row['value'] + 1)
    else:
        result_values.append(row['value'])

# Create a new DataFrame with the results
result_df = pd.DataFrame({'result_value': result_values})
```

will turn into:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN value > 10 THEN value + 1 
        ELSE value 
    END AS result_value
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Thank you, Pavel, this way only can work for the simple scenario. I tried it for my problem but it could not be a good solution.